# Automatic type inferring conventions in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

My python 2.7 project has a class called WorldTables. I pass instances of it to many methods, always under the variable name world_tables.
Unless I specify the PyCharm type hint for every method, I don't get code completion for this class (which I want to have).

However, PyCharm does seem to have a solution for this. If the class name was one word (for example, Player) it would automatically assume that every variable called player is an instance of this class.

After playing around with it a bit, I noticed that this would happen for WorldTables if I passed it under the name of worldtables (instead of world_tables which I currently use). However, that is not how the naming conventions work AFAIK.

Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve adding (hundreds of) type hints or breaking my naming conventions? Something like:

A) Telling pycharm to automatically assume that class_name is ClassName rather than that classname is of ClassName

B) Giving PyCharm a one-off type hint ("every time you see a variable called class_name, assume it is of class ClassName")

C) Any other creative idea that would address this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK code completion behavior can be changed from "Settings-Editor" by pressing Ctrl+Alt+S. You may be find what you are looking for: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Code+completion#Codecompletion-Howtochangecompletionbehavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the type in your docstrings, PyCharm picks up on it.

For eg.

```
def some_func(word_tables):
    """The description of the function.

    :param `WordTables` word_tables: An instance of the `WordTables` class.
    """
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in the question, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve adding type hints to every function that receives a WorldTables object, as that would be in the hundreds.